# Create employee rows for each date in date range

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of employees.
I need to create output which is one row per date in a date range for each employee.  The date range will always be the last 15 days, so it is expected to have 15 rows for each employee.  A "few thousand" employees. This is SQL Server.

```
SAMPLE SOURCE EMP TABLE:  
EMP1  
EMP2 


RESULT:  
EMP1, JAN 1  
EMP1, JAN 2  
EMP1, JAN 3  
EMP2, JAN 1  
EMP2, JAN 2  
EMP2, JAN 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using recursion to build a common expression date table and then `cross join` to the `employee` table.

```
--demo setup
declare @EmpTable table (EmpName varchar(50))
insert into @EmpTable(EmpName) values('emp1'),('emp2')

--use recursion to build a common table expression date table
;WITH dates ([Date])
AS (
    SELECT convert(DATE, '2019-01-01') AS [Date] -- Put the start date here

    UNION ALL

    SELECT dateadd(day, 1, [Date])
    FROM dates
    WHERE [Date] < '2019-01-15' -- Put the end date here 
    )
SELECT e.empname
    ,substring(DATENAME(month, ([date])), 1, 3) + ' ' + DATENAME(day, ([date])) AS [DateDescription]
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN @EmpTable e
ORDER BY empname, [date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767) -- Don't forget to use the maxrecursion option!
```

---

```
| empname | DateDescription |
|---------|-----------------|
| emp1    | Jan 1           |
| emp1    | Jan 2           |
| emp1    | Jan 3           |
| emp1    | Jan 4           |
| emp1    | Jan 5           |
| emp1    | Jan 6           |
| emp1    | Jan 7           |
| emp1    | Jan 8           |
| emp1    | Jan 9           |
| emp1    | Jan 10          |
| emp1    | Jan 11          |
| emp1    | Jan 12          |
| emp1    | Jan 13          |
| emp1    | Jan 14          |
| emp1    | Jan 15          |
| emp2    | Jan 1           |
| emp2    | Jan 2           |
| emp2    | Jan 3           |
| emp2    | Jan 4           |
| emp2    | Jan 5           |
| emp2    | Jan 6           |
| emp2    | Jan 7           |
| emp2    | Jan 8           |
| emp2    | Jan 9           |
| emp2    | Jan 10          |
| emp2    | Jan 11          |
| emp2    | Jan 12          |
| emp2    | Jan 13          |
| emp2    | Jan 14          |
| emp2    | Jan 15          |
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott!  Worked well and ran fast enough for out needs.